# Something is wrong with my loop, but it is not giving me any errors so that I can debug it

Tags: java, loops, hash

I am writing a hashing table and have narrowed down where the issue is coming from.

```
void put(String word, int line)
{
  boolean flag = true;
  int val = getValue(word);
  val = val%10;

  System.out.println(val);

  while ( flag )
  {
    if( total >= words.length )
    {
      System.out.println("2");

      if( words[val] == null )
      {
        System.out.println("3");
        total++;
        words[val] = new Word(word);
        words[val].addLine(line);
        System.out.println(word);
        flag = false;
      }
      else if ( words[val].equals(word) )
      {
        System.out.println("4");
        words[val].addOne();
        words[val].addLine(line);
        flag = false;
      }
      val++;
      if ( val == words.length )
        val=0;

      System.out.println("5");
    }
  }
  System.out.println("2");
}
```

It will only print out val, then continue to give me a loading sign. Is there something wrong with the loop perhaps? But if so why wouldn't it atleast print out 2-5? Any advice would really be appreciated.

Comment: Err, maybe `total` is less than `words.length`?

Comment: It doesn't appear you are initializing `total` anywhere.

Comment: I smell an infinite loop possibility. There are values that can cause "flag" to never be false and the loop never ends (so neither 5 nor 2 are printed)

Comment: haha thank you very much, that was the problem. I had missed that! It was supposed to be if total<=words.length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show us the complete code but from what I can see the only explanation is that you are inside the loop but the outmost if-condition `total >= words.length` is never fulfilled.

```
while(flag) {
  if (...) {  // condition never fulfilled
    ...       // code never reached
  }
}
```

Thus your code is running in an infinite loop without doing anything usefull at all.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure this line:

```
if(total>= words.length){
```

ever evaluates true? I think you are never entering the first if statement.

Comment: If that line is ever false, the loop will spin forever, since no code outside that `if` can change `flag`.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic  is dangerous for an infinite loop, since your flag is only set to false in a

```
if{
  }
else if {
}
```

and you never set it elsewhere.

Plus, if your first if is not true, you enter in an infinite loop right there...

always write an else when you write an if...  or think of what should happen when your condition is not true in a if.  This way you will avoid a lot of bug ;-)

My 2 cents